# Not able to update a model with image field, with out passing an image file with dango rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, updates, imagefield

Using partial_update,trying to update the model with an image field, without giving an image file, no matter how much I try, I end up with this error.

```
'File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\sourcecode\project\app\api.py", line 761, in partial_update
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 207, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 992, in update
    instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 861, in _save_table
    values = [(f, None, (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)))
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 861, in <listcomp>
    values = [(f, None, (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)))
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 286, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'memoryview' object has no attribute '_committed''
```

models.py

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image_file = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=upload_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    is_production_ready = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    return "/".join(['image_file', str(instance.id), filename]
```

Serializers.py

```
class imageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

API.py

```
class imageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = mymodel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = imageSerializer
    parser_classes = (
        MultiPartParser,
        FormParser,
        FileUploadParser,
    )
    
    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        instance = self.get_object()
        data = {}
        data['id'] = request.data['id']
        data['is_production_ready'] = request.data['is_production_ready']
        # data['image_file'] = instance.image_file        
        serializer = imageSerializer(instance, data=data, partial=partial)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("serializer is valid...")
            print("serializer :: ", serializer)            
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Tried with excluding image field in the serializer

```
class imageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
        exclude = ("image_file",)
```

Also defined "blank=True" & "null=True" in models.py

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace from your error?

Comment: Stacktrace added, could you please help us

Comment: From what I understand this error comes from the fact the field is being considered required, but there isn't a file there. I'd check the state of the required attribute once the field is part of the serializer. Perhaps it's required even though it's not on the model?

Comment: Tried with excluding the image field in the serializer, updated above code, you can take a look.